# delete all columns but one

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame that consists of different columns. For example

```
weather  day      ........................   some other column
rainy    Friday                              value
Hot      Saturday                            value
cold     Sunday                              value
```

I am trying to delete all the column except the day one.

I am using different commands

```
df = df.loc[:, ['day']]

drop_list = ["day"]
df = df.drop(df.columns.difference(drop_list), axis=1)

df = df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(['day'])]
```

however, my remain data frame consists only of `nan` values. Any ideas why this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: Why not keep only the day column using `df = df["day"]`?

Comment: same issue here

Comment: `df["day"]` is a series not dataframe

Comment: Is creating a new data set with only the desired column unrealistic here?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep the column you want:

```
df = df[["name"]]
```